# Get value returned form fetch assigned to a variable

Tags: android, fetch, react-native, expo

I want to get the returned value "responseData" assigned to the data variable

```
fetch('http://localhost:8080/users/update, {
          method: 'PUT',
          headers: {'Accept': 'application/json', 'Content-Type': 'application/json'},
          body: JSON.stringify({

              name:this.state.name,
              Level:this.state.activity,
              height:this.state.height,
              weight:this.state.weight
          })})
          .then((response) => {
              return response.json()   
          })
          .then((responseData) => {
            console.log(responseData)   
            this.setState({
              data:responseData
            })

          }

          );
```

I does return true I just want to get it assigned to the variable I already tried to use

```
this.setState({
              data:responseData
            })
```

But it didn't work

Comment: what was the error?

Comment: can you share "responseData" & "response", what actually are coming in? screenshot or  postman response or something else in which we can see formate of data

Comment: @Asad nothing actually it doesnt give any errors it just wont assign the output 'responseData' to data variable I declared data as an empty string

Comment: run your application in debug mode and see what comes in "responseData", insert a breakpoint on it and check its output

Comment: @Asad Thank you I figured it out it was my mistake though I tried to assign a son value to a string variable  `this.setState({
              data:JSON.parse(responseData)
            })`

Comment: @Pabasara Ratnayake welcome. an easy way to figure out this type of error, just debug your code and check step by step what actually is coming wromg.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
fetch('http://localhost:8080/users/update, {
          method: 'PUT',
          headers: {'Accept': 'application/json', 'Content-Type': 'application/json'},
          body: JSON.stringify({

              name:this.state.name,
              Level:this.state.activity,
              height:this.state.height,
              weight:this.state.weight
          })})
          .then((response) => {
              return response.json()   
          })
          .then((responseData) => {
            console.log(responseData)   
            this.setState({
  data:JSON.parse(responseData)
})

          }

          );
```

Answer (score 0):

@Asad Thank you I figured it out it was my mistake though I tried to assign a json value to a string variable this is the correct code

```
this.setState({
  data:JSON.parse(responseData)
})
```